# JPA L2-Cache with Quarkus and Redis

Tags: jpa, redis, quarkus

Is there a way to use Redis as an L2-Caching provider for a Quarkus app ?

I know that there is a Caffeine provider but it is memory-based and it has a high memory consumption. I can trade off network with memory by using external cache provider: like Redis , since we already have it as an enterprise license and I want to utilize that.

I also checked Redisson for for Hibernate but I want it with Quarkus.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not currently implemented. See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9460